# Adding column with existing table which have primary key

Tags: sql-server, composite-primary-key

I need your help...., Please help me

I want to add a new primary key to an existing table which already has 3 columns as composite primary key. But, I do not want to drop the old primary key, since there are many records and the old primary key also have relationship with other table

When I am using this query:

```
alter table hem154
  add indexNO uniqueidentifier default newid()

alter table hem154 
  add CONSTRAINT pk_hem154_indexNo PRIMARY KEY (PK_indexNO)
```

**Note:**

- Hem154 ~ Table Name
- indexNo ~ Column Name which will to added

I get this runtime error:

> Msg 1779, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Table 'hem154' already has a primary key defined on it.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Please help me, how can I do it???

Thanks

Comment: you should drop and add again all primary keys

Comment: You **CANNOT** have more than one primary key for any given table. No way. No trick. No hack. Just not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Drop all primary keys and add Again all primary keys

```
ALTER TABLE hem154
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,ADD PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2,indexNO);
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but nothing different. I still get the same error, please another solution for solve it!!! thanks for ur attention

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one primary key per table.  You can either add a second table that maps your new PK to the old PK, or drop the old PK and add the new one.  Dropping the PK won't drop the columns, it just stops using them as the composite key.  Any tables that were relying on the old key should probably be updated as well to support whatever answer you decide on.

Answer (score 0):

First DROP existing PRIMARY KEY and ADD new composite PRIMARY KEY.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Table1_Col1
GO
```

and then try your code

Comment: example : ALTER TABLE Hem154 DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(indexNo , rollno);

Comment: So your according, I have to drop PK. But I can not to do it, because it's going to lose relationships with other tables, whether any other choice for solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of doing this. From your question, I understand that you want to add one additional column to the existing Primary Key. If they have existing relationships, then it is not possible to do this, without dropping those FK constraints first. Even if you do that, you will not be able to reestablish those FK constraints again, as you have modified the PK.

If you do not need to reestablish those FK relationships, then you can do this:

1. Drop all FK relationships
2. Drop existing PK (data will not be deleted, only the constraint will be dropped)
3. Add new column
4. Recreate PK to include the new column

However, if you cannot drop the existing FK constraints, then I am afraid this is not possible

Comment: Mr. Raj, Thanks for your attention.... So, the conclusion is I have to drop the PK and FK constraints to able add a new column that want to set as the PK?Whether there is no other way? I do not want to lose the relationship with another table

Comment: If you do not want to lose relationships with other tables, then the only way would be to modify those keys as well to include your new PK column, update the data and then reestablish the relationship

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

1. Select/highlight both columns
2. Right click either
3. Press "Set primary key"